# Android Automotive OS Polestar 2 image is failing to be emulated in Android Studio

Tags: android, image, operating-system, automotive

I am trying to simulate the Polestar 2 image gotten from
https://developer.polestar.com/sdk/polestar2-sys-img.xml
and after installing and trying to execute it I receive this message from emulator:
[ADV Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwhkb.png)
The emulator process for AVD Automotive_1024p_landscape_API_29 has terminated

Comment: Hey, getting the same issue, where you able to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to select polestar 2 from SDK Manager. Once the image is installed now launch your polestar emulator from Device Manager. Or follow [Polestar's official Documentation](https://www.polestar.com/se/developer/get-started/emulator/)

Please check the screenshot for your reference.[image: Sdk manager]

Comment: The documatation is down, is there another good tutorial which I could use for the setup? Currently trying to on board and create an app, but I already failing on setup an android automotive os emulator on my macbook with m1pro

Comment: @Antoni I've just texted with the Polestar Support and apparently the Developer Page has been taken down for good. The Emulators have't been updated in a while and their API's won't be publicly available in the future. The links on the [google developer docs](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing/emulator#oem-images) will probably be removed in the future as well.

Comment: @Antoni Just got an update from the polestar support - the developer page is back up again

Comment: @DavidLuhmer still does not work for me, I also had written with the support, they do not even knew this page and were not interested in bringing it back again

Comment: @Antoni looks like they finally updated their website (the support mentioned something of a redesign) - but it looks like the developer section is still broken. Here is the link for Android Studio: https://developer.polestar.com/sdk/polestar_emulator.xml (add it to the SDK Update Sites)

Answer (score 0):

if you are lacate in france ( notice that polstar are block by the govement )
so juste emulate with volvo is possible .
follow this step link https://developer.volvocars.com/android-automotive/sdk/

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem.
Solution was: **free more space on my disk**. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Both Polestar and Volvo emulators work fine for me on an Intel-based Ubuntu laptop (x86_64). Unfortunately neither of them provide arm images and this is exactly the problem, at least in my case - I'm on M1 Air, and both virtual devices won't start up and will crash with the error message you posted if I try to run an app on them